# React Firestore Hooks fail to update when read permission is not longer denied

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, firebase-security

I am using [react-firebase-hooks](https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks), specifically [useDocumentData](https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks), in order to fetch a document and keep it updated.

When the hook is initialized, reading the doc is not permitted yet (due to a certain condition in the Firestore Security Rules not being met), therefor the read fails with `FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

However, after a few minutes there is a change in the database and the document can be read successfully.

If I refresh the page it works properly - **otherwise the hook does not automatically update.**

How can I fix that? I need it to automatically detect that there are permissions to read this document and keep me up to date with its data.

Answer (score 2):

> I need it to automatically detect that there are permissions to read this document and keep me up to date with its data.

You won't be able to do this without making the query yourself.  Once a query listener fails with a permission error, it will not continue to listen. There is no callback to tell you when the query would be allowed again.

You will either to either:

1. Set up another query listener for the data that changed that would allow the original query to work, then re-issue that original query.
2. Or you will need to poll the query periodically to find it if it's working.

Comment: I thought of periodically checking it, however `useDocumentData` does not have a `reload` function - only `useDocumentDataOnce`. I can do a mix of the two but it would get pretty ugly. Any idea on how to make it more elegant?
I also tried your first suggestion but not sure how to re-issue or re-trigger the hook once needed.

Comment: I don't have any advice.  It sounds like maybe you have some new questions to post about React.